# Sharing cookies between multiple level subdomains

Tags: http, cookies, jwt, fetch-api, setcookie

I'm having trouble understanding why cookies are saved in a scenario in my application but not in another.

I have multiple services, each with its own subdomain, making REST requests to each other. In one case, **service.example.com** makes a POST request to **login.example.com**. I'm using the fetch API with `credentials: include`. I've also tested with axios and `withCredentials: true` with the same results. A successful response has a `Set-Cookie` header with a JWT and domain `example.com` and in this scenario the browser saves the cookie as expected.

Now, there's a development environment setup that mirrors the production setup, only every URL is under **dev.example.com**. So in the dev environment **service.dev.example.com** makes the same POST request to **login.dev.example.com**. In this case, if the cookie domain is `example.com`, it continues to work as expected.

However, if I change the cookie domain in the dev environment to be `dev.example.com`, the browser (tested on the latest Chrome and Firefox) won't save the cookie anymore, even though every URL involved is still in a subdomain of the cookie domain.

I've read the [Domain matching section on RFC6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.1.3) and every condition listed there seems to be satisfied by my setup.

Does anyone know why it wouldn't work in this scenario? Is there any way I can have a test setup that won't store cookies that will also be used on requests to the prod environment?

Thanks.

Comment: I am also having the same exact setup and running into the same exact problem!! Did you ever figure out a solution to this?

Comment: BTW for me, cookies issues on `.domain.com` also do not work on `sub1.sub0.domain.com`.

Comment: OP or @Moon, any luck here? In the exact same situation.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but could you please try setting the cookie using the full host including the 4th level subdomains (i.e. service.dev.example.com instead of dev.example.com ).  I have it working in one of my recent project. In theory, this should NOT work as it becomes 3rd party cookie. But it worked. It looks like the 3rd cookie check only go up to 3rd level domains.